# LWC datatable column with a lightning-card inside

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is there a way to embed a lightning-card within LWC datatable's column? My requirement is to display a list of records(each record's content as a lightning-card) in a single column datatable with the ability to perform lazy loading.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of, but not in the way you are thinking of. [Per the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation#creating-custom-data-types):

> **Creating Custom Data Types**
>
> Create your own data types if you want to implement a custom cell, such as a delete row button or an image, or even a custom number display. Here's how you can create custom data types.

So the best you can do is override what a custom cell does.

I would review, thoroughly, the capabilities of `lightning-datatable`, specifically the LWC version (there is a small delta from the Aura flavor, like this custom data type in a cell feature).

If it's not in the [Aura](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/example) or LWC docs (most of the aura features still work in the LWC flavor), it doesn't work/exist and you need to write a custom datatable using SLDS or CSS grids.